# How to add custom css with breakpoint MUI

Tags: material-ui

Hello i'm trying to add padding custom css but this padding should appear on medium size.
I tried to use code like this but it doesn't work

```
 <Grid container spacing={4} sx={md:{p:12}}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change
`sx` to `xs`

[image]

And as demo on MUI [official](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/):

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
    <Item>xs=6 md=8</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
    <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={4}>
    <Item>xs=6 md=4</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6} md={8}>
    <Item>xs=6 md=8</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```